# Cant install ruby version 2.6.6 on OSX Ventura 13.0.1 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby 2.6.6 on a mac running osx 13.0.1. I've tried rbenv and RVM both of which I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and keep getting the same errors.

With rbenv this is the error message -

```
BUILD FAILED (macOS 13.0.1 using ruby-build 20221225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/tm/hhn058ks2kl_3rhmf8z4bds80000gn/T/ruby-build.20230111165419.37628.MFqlgm
Results logged to /var/folders/tm/hhn058ks2kl_3rhmf8z4bds80000gn/T/ruby-build.20230111165419.37628.log

Last 10 log lines:
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_clr
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_fd_isset
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __darwin_check_fd_set
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin22/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.6.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin22/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.6.h
```

Using RVM the error message is this

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j6',
please read /Users/gid/.rvm/log/1673456334_ruby-2.6.6/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

The last lines of the log are the same as the rbenv log apart from the final line which is 

+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

Has anyone else come across this issue? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure 2.6 is supported any more. You might need to use 2.7, a virtual machine, or a Docker container.

Comment: @tadman I was unaware that unsupported installation was a thing? Just for sh*ts and giggles I just installed 1.8.6 through rvm without issue (just had to specific gcc-6 compiler). Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (yes I know I need to update). OP Maybe this will help? https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5146

Comment: @engineersmnky It's difficult to keep up with changes to various operating systems and dependencies, so at some point you have to just call it or risk exposing people to security issues you can't resolve. [Ruby 2.6 support ended 9 months ago](https://endoflife.date/ruby) and Ruby 2.7 ends in around 2 months. People are going to need to move to 3.0 or better to keep getting updates.

Comment: @engineersmnky It's worth noting that the `rbenv` and RVM teams do their best to extend that beyond the usual window, but they can't keep it going forever.

Comment: @tadman maybe I misunderstood your original comment. Yes ruby support ended but installation is still very possible. Either way I agree with the sentiment that updating ruby is critical to mitigate security concerns.

Comment: @engineersmnky Using Ubuntu 18 helps a lot when loading other versions because Ruby considered that a first-class target at the time. Doing 2.6 on 22.10 is probably a different experience. This is why I'm suggesting a VM as a solution. Sometimes you need to use an older operating system to get it to build properly. Using Ubuntu 14 isn't out of the question if working with a very old code base, or if it's even older than that, you may have to get creative.

Comment: Thanks I ended up installing 2.7.7 from rbenv. I'm going to dockerize the app anyway. I'm quite new to docker and so I just wanted to see what is and isn't working locally first before I open another can of worms. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Passing **RUBY_CFLAGS="-w"** worked for me on MacOS Ventura M2.

Example:

```
RUBY_CFLAGS="-w" rbenv install 2.4.0
```